# What do callAction do in Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I am maintaining some Laravel 6 code written by my colleges.

I find that they overrode the callAction method in controllers and initialise some variables in it. But I can't find the callAction method in Laravel 3-8 documentations.

What is the point of initialising variables within the callAction method instead of within the controller's constructor?

```php
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class ControllerA extends Controller
{
    protected $data = [];

    public function callAction($method, $parameters)
    {
        $this->data['title'] = 'Some database query';
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return view('index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callAction(string $method, array $parameters)

> Execute an action on the controller.

source:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.html#method_callAction

Comment: I found that too. But they didn't mention how and when to override it in documentations.

Comment: some people might overwrite this method to allow them to choose which method handles which action

Comment: check this link https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1067

Comment: overall there is no meaning in using it to just assign value to object property it would be considered bad practice and its better to use the constructor in this case.

Comment: Thx. I understand it now